# ImageMagick Perspective Distortion performance

Tags: opengl, 3d, imagemagick, projection, perspectivecamera

My requirement is perspective rotating a user submitted image into a pre-rendered background image (which is actually an image per frame on a video).

The easiest was to use ImageMagick and I wrote a very crude simple bash script to achieve what I needed as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# @author: neurosys
# @Description: Perspective transforms and projects an alpha image
# onto a background image.

if [ $# -ne 11 ]
then
    echo 'Usage: ./map_image.sh background.jpg image.png output.jpg x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4';
    exit;
fi

BG=$1
IMAGE=$2
DEST=$3
TEMP='temp.png'

BG_SIZE_W=$(convert $BG -print "%w\n" /dev/null)
BG_SIZE_H=$(convert $BG -print "%h\n" /dev/null)

IMAGE_W=$(convert $IMAGE -print "%w\n" /dev/null)
IMAGE_H=$(convert $IMAGE -print "%h\n" /dev/null)

X1=$4
Y1=$5

X2=$6
Y2=$7

X3=$8
Y3=$9

X4=${10}
Y4=${11}

OFFSET=15

TRANSFORM="$OFFSET,$OFFSET, $X1,$Y1  $(($IMAGE_W+$OFFSET)),$OFFSET $X2,$Y2  $OFFSET, $(($IMAGE_H+$OFFSET)) $X3,$Y3   $(($IMAGE_W+$OFFSET)), $(($IMAGE_H+$OFFSET)) $X4,$Y4"

echo "Transform matrix: $TRANSFORM"

convert $IMAGE -background transparent -extent $BG_SIZE_W\x$BG_SIZE_H-$OFFSET-$OFFSET $TEMP
convert $TEMP -background transparent -distort Perspective "$TRANSFORM" $TEMP
convert $BG $TEMP -composite $DEST
rm -f $TEMP
```

However, **it takes for about 4 seconds** to produce the desired image on my computer as follows:

```
[neuro@neuro-linux ~]$ time ./map_image.sh bg.png Hp-lovecraft.jpg output.jpg 494 108 579 120 494 183 576 196 && nomacs output.jpg
Transform matrix: 15,15, 494,108  195,15 579,120  15, 267 494,183   195, 267 576,196

real   0m3.852s
user   0m3.437s
sys   0m0.037s
[neuro@neuro-linux ~]$
```

The order of operations as well as the parameters I use in the above ImageMagick script might not be optimal. So, any opinions or alternatives to achieve what I need are greatly welcome.

The images used for the above example are,

- Background
  [image: Background image]
- User submitted image
  [image: User submitted image]
- Output
  [image: Output]

I am wondering if there is a way to speed up this so much so that I can generate frames for a one minute long video (25 fps * 60 sec) under a few seconds?

As a matter of fact, in case this approach fails, I may resort to writing an OpenGL program for this specifically, which I believe will be much faster given hardware leveraging.

Somewhat off-topic note: The background image is prerendered in animation software (3ds Max). In case I resort to writing an opengl renderer, I can import mesh and camera from 3ds Max and do so for better perspective and lighting.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

With the help of guys over at ImageMagick forum, the bottleneck turned out in the first conversion of -extent, which was unneeded.

I ended up combining all the commands into one:

```
convert image.png -background transparent +distort Perspective "1,1, 494,108  201,1 579,120  1, 201 494,183   201, 201 576,196" -compose DstOver -composite bg.png out.png
```

It runs in 0.6 seconds but transparency somehow does not work, so the output image ends up being only the distorted image with black background all around.

**Edit:**

Someone on ImageMagick forums wrote a very fast and clean script that reduced it to 0.13 seconds.

Here is the link, in case anyone needs it: 
https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=29495&p=132182#p132141

Comment: Ensure that IM is built with `OpenMP` support. But if your already thinking about building a solution in `OpenGL`, you can reference [`distort.c`](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/distort.c) for tips & techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Try using MPC format as your $TEMP instead of PNG.  Encoding of MPC is much much faster.  It's designed for use as a temporary file, for use with ImageMagick.

MPC actually creates two files, *.mpc and *.cache, so you need to
remove both.  In your script, set TEMP=temp.mpc and TEMPCACHE=temp.cache,
and then at the end of the script, rm $TEMP TEMPCACHE

See the MPC entry on the [ImageMagick Formats](http://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) page.

Answer (score 1):

If I get the dimensions of an image using your technique, it takes around 0.4 seconds for width and another 0.4 seconds for height. I mean like this:

```
BG_SIZE_W=$(convert $BG -print "%w\n" /dev/null)   # 0.48 sec
BG_SIZE_H=$(convert $BG -print "%h\n" /dev/null)   # 0.48 sec
```

If you get both the width and the height in one go like this, it takes 0.006 seconds altogether on my machine:

```
read BG_SIZE_W BG_SIZE_H < <(identify -ping -format "%w %h" bg.png)
```

I am still looking at the rest of your code.